# Would anyone be able to share an example of pk_chunking working using the python bulk api

Tags: python

I’m new to python and Sales Force.

I have a bulk api extract job working and would like to add pk_chunking.

I use the python library:

```
from salesforce_bulk import SalesforceBulk
```

Adding pk_chunking returns an error:

```
Error returned : BulkBatchFailed('Batch 751O0000006rzOxIAI of job None failed: None')
```

This is what I have at the moment:

```
job = bulk.create_queryall_job(extract_object, contentType='JSON')
        batch = bulk.query(job, query)
        while not bulk.is_batch_done(batch):
                time.sleep(10)
        for result in bulk.get_all_results_for_query_batch(batch):                
            result = json.load(IteratorBytesIO(result))
            bulk.close_job(job)
```

The query I use is:

```
query = f"""
            SELECT {','.join(column_name_list)}   
              FROM {extract_object} 
             WHERE LastModifiedDate > {delta_dt} 
              """
```

The results are loaded into BigQuery.
I will be dealing with some large result sets as I need to load years of data. The query I have shown here will handle the daily incremental run. When it comes to historical loads I’m planning to use a query like:

```
WHERE LastModifiedDate >= {delta_dt} and LastModifiedDate <= {delta_dt}
```

I understand you need to iterate through all the jobs and wait for them to complete. Struggling to get that working.

Thank you

Comment: Could you add more code context of what you've attempted? Asking `salesforce_bulk` for the batch status of the original batch when you use PK Chunking will return an error as that batch is placed in a Not Processed state.

Comment: Hi @David Reed, thanks for getting back to me. I have added my code. Hope this  clarifies what I'm attempting. Cheers